# Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId

Tags: spfield, guid

On a site collection of SP2013 on-premise farm, I found there are many similar log occur every minute. The logs are like:

> Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId
>   '', exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Catastrophic
>   failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt32 lcid, Object varIdBytes)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt32 lcid, Object varIdBytes)

The log level is medium. The same set of log occur every minute with same set of 20 different GUIDs. All related function on the site is working as expected. By using PowerShell to loop thru the site collections I confirmed there is no field using these GUID.

These logs should be related with the search service since the Authentication Authorization log mentioned it is the "Crawler" account in action. However I have no idea why the crawler keep looking for these GUID. I have reset the farm service multiple times already.

The farm was upgraded from SP2010 and it seems no such logs before upgrade.

Any advice? Thank you.